Format issues in jdbc input statement
if I enter "Date"```
If I enter "Date"
If I enter Date
`input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/postgresql-jdbc.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db"
    jdbc_user => user
    jdbc_password => pass
    schedule => "* */4 * * *"  # Schedule to run the query (e.g., every four hour)
    statement => "SELECT * FROM advertising_metrics WHERE date >= current_date - interval '7 day';"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://host:port/"  # Elasticsearch host and port
    user => user
    password => pass
    ssl_enabled => true
    ssl_certificate_authorities => ["/etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt"]
    index => "reporting"   # Name of the index in Elasticsearch
  }
}`
```

I want to transfer last week's data from postgresql to elasticsearch through logstash, but it keeps giving formatting error, I have tried different ways. Also can anyone guide me, I want to keep only recent week data in elasticsearch, removing the previous data continuously, how can I configure that in elasticsearch?  Please tell me what's wrong with the statement format.

What error do you get?

I am getting error in column name date, in postgresql column name is case sensitive, if I use "Date" in statement then it will cut the statement till " considering statement is ended, if I use "Date" to not escape from statement then it will give syntax error near .
If I give simply date then it will say there's no column as date, because it is Date(capitalized in db)

I have added the snapshots of errors too, you may check.
The issue is in column name, I have tried every possible way but I'm not getting it right.
"Date"
"Date"
Date
advertising_metrics.Date
"advertising_metrics.Date"
"advertising_metrics.Date"

Try using single quotes instead of double quotes around the entire SQL statement and double quotes around the case-sensitive field name.

Please review [ask], especially the section about not posting images. Please add the DDL for advertising_metrics as formatted, in-line text. Instead of posting a terse description of attempted code changes, post the full line that was changed and the resulting error messages as formatted, in-line text. The specific version of PostgreSQL should also be mentioned, preferably as a tag. In PostgreSQL, column names are treated as lower-case unless they are enclosed in "s.
